# Subversion (svn) problems with --non-interactive

Tags: svn

So this:

```
/usr/local/bin/svn up --force --no-auth-cache --username my_user
```

works fine (after I supply a password). While this:

```
/usr/local/bin/svn up --force --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --username my_name --password my_pass
```

depending on the svn version returns:

```
svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
svn: E215004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://my_repository'
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
```

for Subversion 1.8.8 and:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://my_repository': authorization failed (https://my_repository)
```

for Subversion 1.6.11.

All this is on the command line (bash) on a Fedora server.

Also this happens for some users and not others (we have svn users who can run with --non-interactive and others who can not, although their passwords are accepted when I run without --non-interactive). I tried deleting the ~/.subversion/auth/ directory and it properly gets recreated when I do `svn up` with credentials.

Pretty stumped at this point. Our repository provider advised we play with the 
`--trust-server-cert` option but I just get no response (errors or other messages) when I do:

```
/usr/local/bin/svn up --force --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --quiet --username my_name --password my_pass --trust-server-cert ~/.subversion/auth_iii/svn.ssl.server/my_cert
```

Appreciate your help...

Comment: 1. **Never** use `--force`, until it *really* needed!!! 2. Try authorization fully by hand (username+password) 3. `--trust-server-cert` doesn't have any additional paramaters

Comment: What happens if everything is OK, Url, Username, Password and interactively server works,  but SVN still gives this error?

Answer (score 7):

False alarm. Turns out we had an unescaped ampersand in the password and that was throwing the whole thing off when in a script (this is why pasting the password when prompted worked). Feel stupid now...

Thanks everyone who read and replied...

Comment: Today I meet this problem,I wasted a whole day,finally I found password error.

Comment: As quick reference: escape an ampersand with `^&` and for a percent `%%`

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem.  Could login with pasting to website, but not via command line.   Also oddly could switch to ssh+svn with a public key and get authenticated ok but then get kicked off.

Was not because of weird characters, I believe there actually is a timeout for some svn servers with this error, because it guards against brute force login attacks using non-interactive.     Waited perhaps 30 min and retried.

Just making note of this because it was another time sink for people to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened, if you execute `svn up` with right user in shell script but got that error, i guess it must be password cache miss in memory.
so, I write another shell script, running that every 5 minute using crontab in order to keep password in memory cache I guess :( for example:
`cd xxxxx && svn up`
hope to help you!